# AdSupport framework not found Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, flurry

I tried running older version of my app which was having Flurry and AdSupport framework.

Xcode automatically removed AdSupport framework.

How do I run this project without removing Flurry?

[image]

Comment: i think u delete it permanently, instead of remove reference... you may click on delete.

Answer (score 0):

add your ad framework into your project

[image]

Comment: After removing AdSupport from my project its not giving any error.But the question is why am I not able to add it?

Comment: if possible link your project